# Parse MIME types in the browser

Tags: javascript

I am interested in parsing XHR requests in the browser. Steps:

1. proxy `send` function - done
2. parse request data - ??

There are 3 MIME types I am interested in:

- `text/plain`
- `application/json`
- `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Is there a function in the browser that I can use to parse the data by `content-type` header?

Comment: You can console.log the whole request (or use step-by-step debugging) and look for that yourself. Can you give it a try?